# How to best incorporate "regression periods" withint SCRUM agile approach?

Tags: regression, development-environment, agile, scrum

We are using Scrum framework in our project. However, the context is such that we cannot afford to release the product without massive regression testing. I know think what would be the best way to incorporate that into our Sprint. I can think of two options so far:

1. Doing a regression after 5 sprints (sorta code freeze)
2. Dedicate a sprint to regression & bug fixing.
3. ...maybe something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extensive period of regression testing is something you should try to avoid at all cost when you want to practice Scrum. Not fully testing your software during or at the end of each sprint breaks one of the most important rules of Scrum, namely that the increment you deliver at the end of each sprint must be potentially releasable. [It must be "done"](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#artifacts-increment).

### Ideal solution

You may need to invest quite heavily in test automation and deployment automation to get to that point, but that is the best way to incorporate your regression tests into the framework. Try to make the effort of testing as low as possible. Deploy often and test at a high frequency.

If you're not there yet, try to invest a substantial amount of your sprint capacity to reduce the time needed for regression testing. You're in a situation with a high technical debt (in testing) and need to get out of that situation.

You might also be able to employ tools that detect coding issues automatically and train your development staff to improve their knowledge in both the domain and the technology.

Dive deep into techniques like:

- Pair Programming
- Acceptance Test Driven Development
- Continuous Integration
- Continuous Delivery

To continuously improve the quality of your product, your process and your people.

### Alternative (non-optimal) solution

*These solutions can temporarily help you, but are not meant to be the definite cure to your problem.*

**Hardening sprint** (shudders)
In the mean time, there are some practices that may work for you in the short run. A dedicated sprint is what is often called a ["hardening" sprint](https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2014/november/do-we-need-a-hardening-sprint). Many teams use this

**Buffer**
Alternatively, have a a separate team do continuous regression testing and make sure that bugs are placed on the product backlog, just like every other work. The development team could keep a buffer in their sprint plan to resolve issues coming out of previous sprints. This is not optimal, as the work that was deemed "done" before turns out to have bugs after all. Make sure the development team already does the bulk of the testing and that only the regression work that won't be possible during the sprint is done by the other team. **The development team has the primary responsibility for the quality of the product.**

### Whatever your team decides to do, make sure you inspect and adapt your processes and tools every sprint

Spend time to find out how these bugs made it into the product and try to find ways to prevent this. Do you need to work closer to your end-users during the sprint so you can catch these items earlier?Do you need to do more automation to find these every night after you check in? Is there an automated check that you can enable in your development environment that could detect these (technical) issues in a Continuous Integration build? In every next sprint spend some time to make sure you plug one of the holes in your process and tools to reduce the chance of these things happening.

Comment: Thanks. You talk about automation, well we do have unit tests and integration tests automated, however it cannot replace intelligent manual testing, especially exploratory testing. I do agree that long periods of regression testing is against SCRUM, on the other hand, we are delivering a system whose malfunction can cause financial losses (immediate).

Comment: Still there may be tools that can detect such issues (Fuzzers are an interesting example). There may be techniques you can build into the product to reduce risk of unwanted financial transactions or detect abuse. Try to do as much of your regression testing in development already. Try to build tests for what these intelligent people are trying to do to your system.

Comment: Or you could do a couple of architectural tricks that runs the old build and the new one side-by-side and detects differences between instances. First step is to stop thinking that regression should take a lot of time and that it must be buffered.

Comment: Thanks. As I can see, the hardening sprints is what could work here. Frankly speaking, I have been on many "SCRUM" projects as a developer and there was always some kind of regression (be it a task called "regression testing" for testers). I think not doing regression is still quite risky. Anyway thanks for the "hardening sprint", I have heard that and cannot recall. I would upvote but I cannot on this account.

Comment: The hardening sprint is an intermediate stage. It may help you now, but try to reduce your need for it as you go along.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody stops you from bringing 'reinforcements' - a couple of testers from other teams/departments or external staff... (if the Product Owner and the Scrum Master are both in consensus than the Management has to play along, usually)
If you want to dedicate a sprint to the testing and debugging than you need to have that task on your Product Backlog (have a chat with your Product Owner etc)...
I have no idea what are you developing, but normally the testing and debugging is part of the regular sprint activity: if not enough testing was done than my guess is that either your Team has been too optimistic when establishing the priorities on the Product Backlog, either your Team had additional requirements from the client and the impact over the other components was not properly analyzed when adding the new customer stories to the PB.
Anyway, when something goes wrong the best thing is to STOP and reconsider your Direction :)